# Convert a single-line Mac bash script to a single-line cmd.exe line

Tags: bash, cmd

I am trying to edit a Mac bash script line into  a line that works in cmd.exe

This line:
`$ bcdata dump bc-airports --bounds $(fio info aoi.shp --bounds)`

obviously doesn't work in cmd.exe due to the $ characters. Easy enough to get rid of those, but the main problem is that this section: `$(fio info aoi.shp --bounds)` is actually returning the value `1659930.833,498443.088,1700759.912,557819.897` that you would get by running that line alone, and passing it in to the main line.

In that sense, the main line really just evaluates to:

`$ bcdata dump bc-airports --bounds 1659930.833,498443.088,1700759.912,557819.897`

Is there any simple way to convert this line from Mac to Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to convert the single line in Mac to two lines in Windows cmd.exe:

This line: `$ bcdata dump bc-airports --bounds $(fio info aoi.shp --bounds)`
translates to:

`` FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %g IN (`fio info W:\FOR\RSI\DKL\General_User_Data\gamos\zfire_polys_2.shp --bounds`) do (SET "variableHere=%g") ``
and
`bcdata dump bc-airports --bounds %variableHere%`

The first line is just to set the variable `variableHere` to the value returned by `fio info W:\FOR\RSI\DKL\General_User_Data\gamos\zfire_polys_2.shp --bounds` (it's a string like 5356.345 4785.456 ).

Then this line 
`bcdata dump bc-airports --bounds %variableHere%` just reads in the value of the variable.

Easy!